# Making local the _G variables & execute location

Tags: lua

**First doubt**

For example, `next` can be stated as local very easily

```
local next = next
```

But how would it be with `table.insert` for example?

Making an anonymous function with **table.insert** inside on a local var would actually work?

**Second doubt**

Is it possible to know from where a function is being executed? This take us back to my first doubt, how can i ensure a _G variable is being executed locally

Really asking because besides default _G variables, i have few more added on my project

Comment: *Is it possible to know from where a function is being executed?* See `debug.traceback()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how would it be with `table.insert` for example?

```
local table = table
```

> how can i ensure a _G variable is being executed locally

It is still the same function value. You just added a local reference to it. Local variables can be looked up faster. You would have to call a function very often to really benefit from doing that.

This is opinionated but that opinion is shared among most programmers:

Don't waste time on premature optimization. Don't create local references for every global you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

With load() you can give Lua code an own environment.
Normally (without that own environment) _G (5.1) or _ENV (since 5.3) is used.
Example you can play with...

```
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
> load('do local tab, concat, insert = {}, concat, insert insert(tab, "Hello World!") return concat(tab) end', 'own_env', 't', {concat = table.concat, insert = table.insert})()
Hello World!
> load('do local tab, concat, insert = {}, concat, insert insert(tab, "Hello World!") return concat(tab) end', 'own_env', 't')()
[string "own_env"]:1: local 'insert' is not callable (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [string "own_env"]:1: in main chunk
        (...tail calls...)
        [C]: in ?
```

Source: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load